# How to add action for h:graphicImage Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I have a graphicalImage and I want a method in the backingBean to be fired up on clicking on the image.Below is the code snippet that i am using but it is not working. Please help.

```
<h:graphicImage value="../resources/images/delete_button.png"
onclick="editBean.deleteStudyPlan"
style="float:center;height: 18px; width:20px;"
title="Delete the studyplan"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a `<h:commandLink>` or `<p:commandLink>` and specify the `action` there.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{editBean.deleteStudyPlan}">
    <h:graphicImage ... />
</h:commandLink>
```

Alternatively, you can just specify the image as a CSS background image of the command link or button.

The `onclick` surely isn't a method expression to a JSF backing bean action method. It's a JavaScript function handler. JavaScript is an entirely different language which runs in the webbrowser, working on the HTML code produced by JSF.

Comment: I changed the same like this <p:commandLink target="editBean.selectedStudyPlan" value="${categorey}" actionListener="#{editBean.deleteStudyPlan}" >
   <h:graphicImage value="../resources/images/delete_button.png"
      style="float:center;height: 18px; width: 20px;"
       title="Delete the studyplan"/>
   </p:commandLink>. But now it is opening up an empty window which i dont want.The method is getting executed

Comment: Remove the `target` attribute and use it only once you really understand what it does.

Comment: Hi Yes now it is working but I want to set the value of the selected object to a field in the BackingBean. How to do it.

Comment: Use `action="#{editBean.deleteStudyPlan(studyPlan)}` or `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`. This is however a completely different quesiton. Press `Ask Question` button in right top if you stucks.